# React,js + Prisma better way to update sql with a button

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

```
async function change_status(object_id:number){
      const response = await fetch('/api/db', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.parse(`{"id":${object_id}}`)
      });
    
      if (!response.ok){
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return await response.json();
}
```

**I want this button to change an int in mysql**

```
<button onClick={() => change_status(object.id)}>
    change Status
</button>
```

**/api/db.ts**

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest,res: NextApiResponse) {
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const object_id = data.id;
  const find_object = await prisma.objects.findFirstOrThrow({
    where: {id:object_id}
  });
  if (find_object.status == 0){
    var change = await prisma.objects.update({
      where: { id: object_id },
      data: { status:1 },
    })
  }
  else {
    var change = await prisma.objects.update({
      where: { id: object_id },
      data: { status:0 },
    })
  }
  res.json(change);
}
```

**I get this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`**

Is there any better way to code the button or pass object_id without a JSON

Comment: Console.log your `req.body` It seems it’s  not a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your fetch to

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/db', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: object_id }),
});
```

And in your api simply

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { id } = req.body;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna drop some information about Prisma when I had these kinda problems with it.

1 - don't forget to use `body: JSON.stringify(),` (this might be the issue here)

2 - config your header as well.

3 - I would suggest avoiding the `var` keyword because of some sort of things ( like hoisting).

4 - stick with Prisma documentation.they almost covered everything